# Clojure: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure

I know there are a lot of questions out there with this headline, but I can't glean my answer from them, so here goes.

I'm an experienced programmer, but fairly new to Clojure.  I'm trying to parse a RTF file by converting it to a  HTML file then calling the html parser.

The converter I'm using (unrtf) always prints to stdout, so I need to capture the output and write the file myself.

```
  (defn parse-rtf
    "Use unrtf to parse a rtf file"
    [#^java.io.InputStream istream charset]
    (let [rtffile (File/createTempFile "parse" ".rtf" (File. "/vault/tmp/"))
          htmlfile (File/createTempFile "parse" ".ohtml" (File. "/vault/tmp/"))
          command (str "/usr/bin/unrtf "
                        (.getPath rtffile)
                  )
         ]
      (try
        (with-open [rtfout  (FileOutputStream. rtffile)]
          (IOUtils/copy istream rtfout))
        (let [ proc (.exec (Runtime/getRuntime) command)
               ostream (.getInputStream proc)
               result (.waitFor proc)]
          (if (> result 0)
            (
              (println "unrtf failed" command result)
              ; throwing an exception causes a parse failure to be logged
              (throw (Exception. (str "RTF to HTML conversion failed")))
            )
            (
              (with-open [htmlout  (FileOutputStream. htmlfile)]
                (IOUtils/copy ostream htmlout))
              ; since we now have html, run it through the html parser
              (parse-html (FileInputStream. htmlfile) charset)
           )
          )
        )
      (finally
        (.delete rtffile)
        (.delete htmlfile)
      )
      )))
```

The exception points to the line with

```
(IOUtils/copy ostream htmlout))
```

which really confuses me, since I used that form earlier (just after the try:) and it seems to be OK there.  I can't see the difference.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You're using parentheses incorrectly. In particular your if statement is wrong. Parentheses are not curly braces. When you have an extra pair, you're invoking the inner expression as a function. You want `(if condition something something-else)` and you have `(if condition (something) (something-else))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have correctly pointed out, you can't just add extra parentheses for code organization to group forms together. Parentheses in a Clojure file are tokens that delimit a list in the corresponding code; lists are evaluated as s-expressions - that is, the first form is evaluated and the result is invoked as a function (unless it names a special form such as `if` or `let`).

In this case you have the following:

```
(
  (with-open [htmlout  (FileOutputStream. htmlfile)]
    (IOUtils/copy ostream htmlout))
  ; since we now have html, run it through the html parser
  (parse-html (FileInputStream. htmlfile) charset)
)
```

The `IOUtils/copy` function has an integer return value (the number of bytes copied). This value is then returned when the surrounding `with-open` macro is evaluated. Since the `with-open` form is the first in a list, Clojure will then try to invoke the integer return value from `IOUtils/copy` as a function, resulting in the exception that you see.

To evaluate multiple forms for side-effects without invoking the result from the first one, wrap them in a `do` form; this is a special form that evaluates each expression and returns the result of the final expression, discarding the result from all others. Many core macros and special forms such as `let`, `when`, and `with-open` (among many others) accept multiple expressions and evaluate them in an implicit `do`.

Comment: I was confused by the let and function forms that allowed multiple statements.  Going back and re-reading some of my sources, I see that these are the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Even inside a function or let form, if you used an extra pair of parens like you do in this code, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I didnt try to run your code, just had a look at it, and after the `if (> result 0)` you have `((println ...)(throw ...))` without a [do](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/do). Having an extra parens causes the returned value from the inner parens to be treated as a function and get executed.

try to include it, like this `(do (println ...) (throw ...))`